# What is the difference between the meaning of two statements?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, future-tense

I'm confused with passive future. What is the difference between the meaning of two following statements :

```
 She will go as soon as the stores will be opened.
 She will go as soon as the stores are opened.
```

does anyone could explain it?

Thank

Comment: Hey @Hemfri welcome to the community. Please consider the following before posting questions: 1) always do an extensive search to see if someone has already asked your question. 2)supplement your question with references, research and links to help contributes answer your question.

Comment: Hi @Fermichem thanks for your attention. I just wanted to write a letter for someone, but my English isn't good enough to realize my grammatical errors. I searched a lot but I confused more, and decided to ask my question here to get some help. My apologies if my question is so basic.

Comment: No need to apologize :) I just wanted to help. By giving people more information they'll be able to help you more quickly.

Comment: @Fermichem  Thank you!

Comment: Native speakers would say "She will go as soon as the stores are open." The first version may seem logical, but it is not idiomatic English.

Comment: @Kate or just "as soon as the stores open."